# Searchlogic gem install -> installs gems that aren't searchlogic (and then doesn't install searchlogic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, searchlogic

```
% gem install searchlogic -v2.4.28
Fetching: arel-2.2.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: tzinfo-0.3.31.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activemodel-3.1.3
Successfully installed arel-2.2.1
Successfully installed tzinfo-0.3.31
3 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for activemodel-3.1.3...
Installing ri documentation for arel-2.2.1...
Installing ri documentation for tzinfo-0.3.31...
Installing RDoc documentation for activemodel-3.1.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for arel-2.2.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for tzinfo-0.3.31...
```

.... what is going on here?
shouldn't search logic be installed, and not these... gems I don't need?

Comment: Is it already installed? Here's log from my machine: https://gist.github.com/1515249

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's installing the dependencies for the gem, as it depends on activerecord and these are the dependencies for the activerecord gem. You should check to see if the gem is not already installed.

Comment: the problem is, when I do "bundle exec script/server -p3001" I get the error: Missing these required gems: searchlogic  = 2.4.28